# Webpack css-loader source map shows server paths even in production

Tags: webpack, source-maps, css-loader, webpacker

Setting `sourceMap: true` with the webpack `css-loader` always results in some private server paths getting displayed in the resulting js bundle, as well as a lot of other code. E.g.

```
{"version":3,"sources":["/private/path/to/project/flexboxgrid2.css"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAA;EACE;BLAH BLAH BLAH..."}
```

This occurs even when the project's `devtool` is set to `source-map`, which I thought meant all source map code was moved to an external source map file, rather than inline.

This is annoying because

1. it means our js bundles have different fingerprints depending on
   which server they were generated on, which messes with our assets
   pipeline.
2. anyone can see the internal directory structure of our production
   servers, which isn't great.

The only solution is to turn off source maps for `css-loader`.

Is there any way to keep source maps turned on but have the above code not included in the js?